# Spring boot: using EntityListeners on joint tables

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, join

We're using an `@EntityListener` class to act on some changes to the repository.

**Similary, is there a way to listen to changes that occur on a join table?**

Example : `service_vehicles` table in db

We have services and vehicles tables and we can assign vehicles to services (many to one)

The following `@EntityListener` is not triggered when I add a vehicle to a service.

```
@PostPersist
@PostUpdate
@PostRemove
private void afterAnyOperation(Object object) {

        LOG.debug("Handling entity change for obj:{}", object);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible to register a listener via a config property `hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-update` and set a class name that implements `PostCollectionUpdateEventListener`.